# Is it possible to left join a sql select statement with conditions with a table? or do I have to create intermediate queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

So I have a Invoice table where I created the following query, let's call it "IntInvoice"

```
SELECT *
FROM [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control]
WHERE [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].[Décision prise] is null
and
[U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].Concatenar is not null
and
[U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].N_AVD is not null;
```

next I created another query to left join a different table with the "IntInvoice" query

```
SELECT IntInvoice.*
FROM IntInvoice
LEFT JOIN Int_Account 
ON IntInvoice.Concatenar=Int_Account.Concatenar
WHERE Int_Account.Concatenar Is Null and IntInvoice.Concatenar is not null;
```

it works fine as it is, but is it possible to have it all in the same query to avoid having to create a lot of them when I have to work with the data?

Comment: Multiple queries is the way MS Access works.  What data base are your underlying tables stored in?  If it's Microsoft's own ACE engine there's nothing else you can do.  But if your data is stored in some external data base as linked tables, you can code a passthrough query which, as the names says, will pass through whatever query you code directly to the underlying data base for execution.  All syntax must conform to the underlying data base's particular flavor of SQL.

Comment: Can you not just add Int_Account to the first query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clarifying my comment, I would think you can combine these two into a query:

```
SELECT [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].*
FROM
  [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control]
  LEFT JOIN Int_Account 
    ON [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].Concatenar=Int_Account.Concatenar
WHERE
  [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].[Décision prise] is null and
  [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].Concatenar is not null and
  [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].N_AVD is not null and
  Int_Account.Concatenar Is Null and
  -- this is duplicated from above so should not be necessary:
  [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].Concatenar is not null
```

There are a few cases where this would not be possible (or easy), but this was a relatively simple query to integrate.

Examples would be if two queries both did aggregate/group by and you wanted to join the results.

-- EDIT 4/20/2022 --

Per your latest comment, where Int_Account is actually the following:

```
SELECT * FROM U_Concatenar_AccountManagement WHERE 
U_Concatenar_AccountManagement.Status_AVD="À traiter";
```

You could rewrite the query above as follows:

```
SELECT [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].*
FROM
  [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control]
  LEFT JOIN [U_Concatenar_AccountManagement] ON
    [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].Concatenar=Int_Account.Concatenar and
    [U_Concatenar_AccountManagement].Status_AVD="À traiter"
WHERE
  [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].[Décision prise] is null and
  [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].Concatenar is not null and
  [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].N_AVD is not null and
  [U_Concatenar_AccountManagement].Concatenar Is Null -- fixed
   --  [Int_Account.Concatenar] Is Null  -- replaced this
```

My guess (and this is just a guess) is that you added:

```
[U_Concatenar_AccountManagement].Status_AVD="À traiter"
```

To the "where" clause instead of as part of the join.  I don't know Access very well, but in standard SQL, these mean two very different things:

```
from x                               from x
  left join y on x.id = y.id           left join y on x.id = y.id
     and y.z = 'Foo'                 where y.z = 'Foo'
```

The one on the left preserves the left join and only left joins on records where the condition is true.  The one on the right effectively converts your left join to an inner join, which based on the rest of your query seems like it *would* return zero results (you only want records where you did not find a match in y).

Give that a try and see if it works.  Hopefully you can follow this pattern and eliminate the need for so many subqueries (queries of queries).  In the long run these are so much harder to maintain because you have to follow the trail of breadcrumbs back every time.

-- EDIT 4/21/2022 --

I know you've put this to bed, but I had to know...  it turns out as you discovered, Access does not support where conditions in the join.  I find this crazy.  You can, however, accomplish the same goal by creating an inline subquery and putting your condition there.

Here is what worked for me:

```
SELECT [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].*
FROM [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control]
LEFT JOIN (select * from U_Concatenar_AccountManagement where Status_AVD="À traiter") AS X
  ON [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].Concatenar = X.Concatenar
WHERE
  [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].[Décision prise] Is Null AND 
  [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].Concatenar Is Not Null AND
  [U_Concatenar_Invoice Control].N_AVD Is Not Null AND
  X.Concatenar Is Null;
```

In my opinion, this is no better than the approach you are using to have two queries, one that calls the other.  What you gain in conciseness you lose in transparency.  Pick one or the other; neither is ideal.

Comment: Thank you, that's an amazing solution, it works and eliminates IntInvoice.
Do you know if it is possible to eliminate the Int_Account query?
Int_Account has the following:
---------------
SELECT *
FROM U_Concatenar_AccountManagement
WHERE U_Concatenar_AccountManagement.Status_AVD="À traiter";
---------------
I replaced Int_Account with U_Concatenar_AccountManagement but it gives me 0 results.

Comment: Hi Hambone, tested the latest solution but unfortunately it gives an error when placing the new condition just before the "where".
Than you for all the help, I will carry on with the project with the subqueries to not lose more time on this problem. Once again tks for all the help.

Comment: I'm not an expert in MS Access, but I work with someone who is...  I'm going to ask him.  Also, I found an error where I was referring to the old alias (query).  I fixed that in the attempted answer and commented where I messed up.

Comment: My god, Hambone. You did it, you bloody did it!! Thank you so much. You went above and beyond, I had already given up and you still pushed :) , amazing and I can't really thank you enough. It works like a charm. 
I too think that the 2 queries approach is slightly superior but I will save a different version with the other approach to show and see what they prefer.
Thank you thank you thank you.